# Installing Sphinx on OS X Lion with Postgresql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

So I installed postgresql and the thinking-sphinx gem. I cd into my sphinx download folder and try to run ./configure --with-postgresql

I receive the following message:

#

ERROR: cannot find MySQL include files.

Check that you do have MySQL include files installed.
The package name is typically 'mysql-devel'.

If include files are installed on your system, but you are still getting
this message, you should do one of the following:

1) either specify includes location explicitly, using --with-mysql-includes;
2) or specify MySQL installation root location explicitly, using --with-mysql;
3) or make sure that the path to 'mysql_config' program is listed in
   your PATH environment variable.

To disable MySQL support, use --without-mysql option.

#

What should I do? I have also tried install sphinx using brew, but that hasn't worked either. I'm desperate. I just spent three hours trying to configure this, and I have gotten nowhere.

My sphinx.yml looks like this, and i'm not sure if it's correct:

```
development:
  port: 9310
  bin_path: "/usr/bin"
  searchd_binary_name: searchd
  indexer_binary_name: indexer

test:
  port: 9310
  bin_path: "/usr/bin"
  searchd_binary_name: searchd
  indexer_binary_name: indexer

production:
  version: '1.10-beta'
```

Comment: I'd say use `--without-mysql`.

Answer (score 5):

I used homebrew. According to the docs at thinking-sphinx, you need the mysql extension even if you are using postgres.

I mucked around with a few configurations but sphinx kept looking to connect to MySQL.

This worked for me:

```
brew install sphinx --mysql --pgsql
```

Which configured:

```
./configure --with-mysql --with-pgsql
```

Then it seemed to work.

See:
https://github.com/pat/thinking-sphinx

Comment: where do I need to go to run ./configure?

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Tass. You wold run Sphinx's configure script with `--without-mysql` & `--with-pgsql`. I have PostgreSQL installed in `/usr/local`; therefor, my configuration options would be:

```
shell~> ./configure --without-mysql --with-pgsql=/usr/local
```